# chess.js and chessboard.js integration

Tags: chessboard.js

I need to use chess.js and chessboard.js but some errors occour on console.

My code is:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.13.4/chess.js" integrity="sha512-40VRp1+fauX7g61ZdQpOiOJTkBbYwVlTLjCXHK9Svf0Mmz9K8Smg5k6LVrc0eEc9+pApf1HNL6Cim/wFqZeRkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chessboard-js/1.0.0/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha512-WfASs5HtTgTL/eZsLaOftSN9wMQl7WZGlU5UiKx/yxTViMfGh9whWRwKAC27qH8VtZJqSMqDdbq2uUb1tY3jvQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

and the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at chess.js:252:1)
```

The line is:

```
export const BLACK = 'b'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using version 0.12.1

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.12.1/chess.min.js" integrity="sha512-rIescAjPgXHz3WaxrSjaOl5iZfvBVIehYe+EF+d+DAdFNgV10QBT8d5APBjcGFKES0iVUYjBilvpck7gOe7CLg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```